# getting null values for textbox for selected checkbox in a row while sending from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${list}">

            <tr>
                <td align="center"><%-- <input type="hidden"
                    value="${product.productId}" name="id"> --%> <c:out
                        value="${product.productName}" /></td>
                <td align="center"><c:out value="${product.productPrice}" /></td>
                <td align="center"><input type="text" name="quantity<c:out value="${product.productId}" />"
                    value="<%=1%>" /></td>
                <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems"
                    value="<c:out value=" ${product.productId}"/>"/></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

getting null value for quantity for particular selected row by checkbox in servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in line `name="quantity<c:out value="${product.productId}" />"`. Try changing to `name='quantity<c:out value="${product.productId}" />'` if your intention is to have name, e.g. like name=quantity1, name=quantity2, etc.

Or alternatively set the value of the quantity as ${product.productId}, e.g.

```
<td align="center"><input type="text" name="quantity" value='<c:out value="${product.productId}" />' /></td>
```

**Update:**

Try to simplify your problem before jumping into the loop.
Now are you able to process this as `JSP` POST form and see if you are able retrieve a value out of quantity?

```
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="quantity" value="some default value before user overrides this" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: value would be entered by user and want to get that value

Comment: name='quantity<c:out value="${product.productId}" />' after doing this still got null values